# Are questions about ethics on-topic?

Tags: discussion

https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2600/are-engineering-ethics-objective-or-subjective?noredirect=1#comment4275_2600

This question was closed for being off-topic. The argument was that it is a question about ethics in general, not about engineering ethics specifically, and thus out of scope.

The reason I asked is that the community needs a clear answer to this question, even if not in my question particularly. If ethics are subjective, they are not properly in scope for a site based around [objectively answering questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).

Comment: Would you like me to migrate your closed question from Engineering SE to Meta Engineering SE?

Comment: Whatever you think is appropriate.

Comment: Related, non-duplicate Meta question: http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/274/are-engineering-ethics-objective-or-subjective